# Is there a prime for every starting sequence of digits?

Tags: prime-numbers

Suppose, I have a random finite sequence of digits (that doesn't start from 0).

Is it true that there is a prime number (no matter how big) that starts with this sequence of digits?

`Examples:
3 => 31
10 => 101
123 => 1237
1000 => 100007`